# Cypher - Match node by properties of its connected nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We've built a Neo4j model where each "Entity" node is linked to a set of "Attribute" nodes, each of which carrying one "label" and one "value" properties.

What would be the (most efficient) Cypher request to fetch that "Entity" node that has all the requested "Attribute" neighbours given their "label"/"value" properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use the `HAS` relationship type, and you pass a `props` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) containing a list of the desired label/value pairs in the following sample format: `[['foo', 123], ['bar', true], ['foo', 234], ['baba', 'black sheep']]`, this query should work:

```
MATCH (e:Entity)
WHERE ALL(p IN $props WHERE SIZE([(e)-[:HAS]->(a:Attrib) WHERE a[p[0]] = p[1] | 1]) > 0)
RETURN e
```

[UPDATE]

The returned `e` nodes must have related `Attrib` node(s) containing all the property name and value pairs that are in the `props` parameter.

A [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) must specify a projection, so this query just uses 1 as the projection since we don't care about the contents of the generated list. We only care about the testing size of the list.

To test the above query with the sample `props` parameter value, first create some suitable nodes and relationships. For example:

```
CREATE (e:Entity {id: 1}),
  (e)-[:HAS]->(:Attrib {id: 22, foo: 123, bar: true}),
  (e)-[:HAS]->(:Attrib {id: 33, baba: 'black sheep'}),
  (e)-[:HAS]->(:Attrib {id: 44, foo: 234})
```

Comment: Alas! It does not.
This is what I tried:
`:params {props: [["Name": "Name_1"]]}`
But when I try and launch the request:
`Expected Long(0) to be a org.neo4j.values.storable.TextValue, but it was a org.neo4j.values.storable.LongValue`

Comment: Now could you please explain `a[p[0]] = p[1] | 1]` ?

Comment: Much obliged, Sir. It works. Thanks.
Now, can you see anything wrong with my own proposed answer (see below)? And then, why the "Expected Long(0) to be a org.neo4j.values.storable.TextValue, but it was a org.neo4j.values.storable.LongValue" error above?

Comment: Ok, now I see where the difference stands between your answer and mine:
In my question the entity creation pattern was like:

CREATE (e:Entity {id: 1}), (f:Entity {id: 2}),
(e)-[:HAS]->(:Attribute {id: 10, label: 'colour', value: 'blue'}),
(e)-[:HAS]->(:Attribute {id: 11, label: 'shape', value: 'round'}),
(f)-[:HAS]->(:Attribute {id: 20, label: 'colour', value: 'red'}),
(f)-[:HAS]->(:Attribute {id: 21, label: 'shape', value: 'round'})

Then my question was to query on the entity whose 'colour' is 'blue' and 'shape' is 'round' for instance.

Comment: I'll accept your answer though it doesn't exactly answer my question, because it was of a great help! Again, thanks.
Could you possibly update your answer to match my question?

Comment: You were trying to compare a string value (in props) to a long value (in your actual data).

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up creating the following attributes:

```
:params {props: [["name", "Athanase"], ["age", 22], ["color", "blue"]]}
```

I then updated the query as such:

```
MATCH (e:Entity) WHERE ALL(p IN $props WHERE SIZE ([(e)-[:HAS]->(a:Attrib) WHERE (a.label = p[0] AND a.value = p[1]) | 1]) > 0) RETURN e;
```

Looks like it is working fine.

Comment: The thing though is that I still don't quite understand @cybersam 's proposed answer. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This answer requires your node to have an awkward pair of `label` and `value` properties. That is not necessary, and not best practice. My answer shows how to avoid that and allows you to use arbitrary property names.

Comment: Having the 'label' and 'value' properties set on an 'Attribute' node is not an option. The model was so designed for very specific purposes which I won't detail here for confidentiality reasons. Best practices are that good only, and I have learnt over the years how to always question them. That being said, I gained some useful knowledge from your answer for which I am indeed grateful.